# cannot stub method on view in a view spec Rails 4/ Rspec-Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I try to stub a helper method in a view spec in a Rails 4.2 application

```
describe 'cities/index' do
  let(:cities) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:city, 5) }

  before do
    allow(view).to receive(:cities).and_return{ cities }
  end

  it 'shows the list of all the cities' do
    render
    cities.each do |city|
      expect(rendered).to have_link(city.name, href: city_path(city))
    end
  end
end
```

but I get the error

```
 Failure/Error: allow(view).to receive(:cities).and_return{ cities }
       #<#<Class:0x000000061886d8>:0x00000003d20d68 @_routes=nil, @_config={}, @view_renderer=#<ActionView::Renderer:0x00000003d20ef8 @lookup_context=#<ActionView::LookupContext:0x00000003d21060 @details_key=nil, @details={:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}, @skip_default_locale=false, @cache=true, @prefixes=["", "cities"], @rendered_format=nil, @view_paths=#<ActionView::PathSet:0x00000003d20fe8 @paths=[#<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x00000005951ff0 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x00000005951fc8 @data=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache::SmallCache:0x00000005951fa0 @backend={}, @default_proc=#<Proc:0x000000032a5230@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:49 (lambda)>>>, @path="/home/nafaa/RailsProjects/curiocity/app/views">, #<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x000000059535a8 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x00000005953418 @data=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache::SmallCache:0x00000005953328 @backend={}, @default_proc=#<Proc:0x000000032a5230@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:49 (lambda)>>>, @path="/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views">]>>>, @request=#<ActionController::TestRequest:0x00000006192e08 @env={"rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x00000007b1a808>, "rack.errors"=>#<StringIO:0x00000007b1a8a8>, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>true, "rack.run_once"=>false, "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", "SERVER_NAME"=>"example.org", "SERVER_PORT"=>"80", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "rack.url_scheme"=>"http", "HTTPS"=>"off", "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "CONTENT_LENGTH"=>"0", "HTTP_HOST"=>"test.host", "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"0.0.0.0", "HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"Rails Testing", "action_dispatch.routes"=>#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x000000059671c0>, "action_dispatch.parameter_filter"=>[:password], "action_dispatch.redirect_filter"=>[], "action_dispatch.secret_token"=>nil, "action_dispatch.secret_key_base"=>"7368248a4a51e0ae4789e5f6d20884c032289b9da1a1e916d817efebed052e961d299ed73a8e8b90f33ed9314bb24454845f9ddc3acf18445aa3f6625ed9db63", "action_dispatch.show_exceptions"=>false, "action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"=>true, "action_dispatch.logger"=>#<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x000000057f3ca8 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x000000057f3b90 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x00000001f097f8 @datetime_format=nil>, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x000000057f3b40 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<File:/home/nafaa/RailsProjects/curiocity/log/test.log>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x000000057f3b18 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x000000057f3ac8>>>>, "action_dispatch.backtrace_cleaner"=>#<Rails::BacktraceCleaner:0x0000000618a0c8 @filters=[#<Proc:0x00000006189fb0@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:14>, #<Proc:0x00000006189f88@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:15>, #<Proc:0x00000006189f38@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:16>, #<Proc:0x00000006189ba0@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:29>], @silencers=[#<Proc:0x00000006189b78@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:19>], @root="/home/nafaa/RailsProjects/curiocity/">, "action_dispatch.key_generator"=>#<ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator:0x00000007888a68 @key_generator=#<ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator:0x00000007888a90 @secret="7368248a4a51e0ae4789e5f6d20884c032289b9da1a1e916d817efebed052e961d299ed73a8e8b90f33ed9314bb24454845f9ddc3acf18445aa3f6625ed9db63", @iterations=1000>, @cache_keys=#<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x00000007888a40 @backend={"signed_global_ids64"=>"4\xAC\xEB^\x0E\xD4\x85\xCC\xD5\xF0\xBC\x9BT\xB3}\eRu\xD8\x8C\xB0\xCE\xA4\bwi\x9A\xD3a\xAAn\x0Ee\x10\x01\xE7\xFF1\xFA\x12\x04\xBEZ\xF5\x90\xA1\x95.7\xA5\rzJ\xDC~\x04;\xE4\xC1\xE9\x84w|)"}, @default_proc=nil>>, "action_dispatch.http_auth_salt"=>"http authentication", "action_dispatch.signed_cookie_salt"=>"signed cookie", "action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_salt"=>"encrypted cookie", "action_dispatch.encrypted_signed_cookie_salt"=>"signed encrypted cookie", "action_dispatch.cookies_serializer"=>:json, "action_dispatch.cookies_digest"=>nil, "rack.session"=>{}, "rack.session.options"=>{:key=>"rack.session", :path=>"/", :domain=>nil, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :defer=>false, :renew=>false, :sidbits=>128, :cookie_only=>true, :secure_random=>SecureRandom, :id=>"14e3e35975e7a758051ecf0751adcac0"}, "action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"=>{:controller=>"cities", :action=>"index"}}, @filtered_parameters=nil, @filtered_env=nil, @filtered_path=nil, @protocol=nil, @port=nil, @method=nil, @request_method=nil, @remote_ip=nil, @original_fullpath=nil, @fullpath=nil, @ip=nil, @uuid=nil>, @response=#<ActionController::TestResponse:0x00000006189268 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x000000061891c8>, @stream=#<ActionDispatch::Response::Buffer:0x00000006189128 @response=#<ActionController::TestResponse:0x00000006189268 ...>, @buf=[], @closed=false>, @header={}, @status=200, @sending_file=false, @blank=false, @cv=#<MonitorMixin::ConditionVariable:0x00000006189100 @monitor=#<ActionController::TestResponse:0x00000006189268 ...>, @cond=#<Thread::ConditionVariable:0x000000061890d8>>, @committed=false, @sending=false, @sent=false, @content_type=nil, @charset=nil, @cache_control={}, @etag=nil>, @params={}, @_assigns={"request"=>#<ActionController::TestRequest:0x00000006192e08 @env={"rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x00000007b1a808>, "rack.errors"=>#<StringIO:0x00000007b1a8a8>, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>true, "rack.run_once"=>false, "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", "SERVER_NAME"=>"example.org", "SERVER_PORT"=>"80", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "rack.url_scheme"=>"http", "HTTPS"=>"off", "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "CONTENT_LENGTH"=>"0", "HTTP_HOST"=>"test.host", "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"0.0.0.0", "HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"Rails Testing", "action_dispatch.routes"=>#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x000000059671c0>, "action_dispatch.parameter_filter"=>[:password], "action_dispatch.redirect_filter"=>[], "action_dispatch.secret_token"=>nil, "action_dispatch.secret_key_base"=>"7368248a4a51e0ae4789e5f6d20884c032289b9da1a1e916d817efebed052e961d299ed73a8e8b90f33ed9314bb24454845f9ddc3acf18445aa3f6625ed9db63", "action_dispatch.show_exceptions"=>false, "action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"=>true, "action_dispatch.logger"=>#<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x000000057f3ca8 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x000000057f3b90 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x00000001f097f8 @datetime_format=nil>, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x000000057f3b40 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<File:/home/nafaa/RailsProjects/curiocity/log/test.log>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x000000057f3b18 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x000000057f3ac8>>>>, "action_dispatch.backtrace_cleaner"=>#<Rails::BacktraceCleaner:0x0000000618a0c8 @filters=[#<Proc:0x00000006189fb0@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:14>, #<Proc:0x00000006189f88@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:15>, #<Proc:0x00000006189f38@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:16>, #<Proc:0x00000006189ba0@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:29>], @silencers=[#<Proc:0x00000006189b78@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:19>], @root="/home/nafaa/RailsProjects/curiocity/">, "action_dispatch.key_generator"=>#<ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator:0x00000007888a68 @key_generator=#<ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator:0x00000007888a90 @secret="7368248a4a51e0ae4789e5f6d20884c032289b9da1a1e916d817efebed052e961d299ed73a8e8b90f33ed9314bb24454845f9ddc3acf18445aa3f6625ed9db63", @iterations=1000>, @cache_keys=#<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x00000007888a40 @backend={"signed_global_ids64"=>"4\xAC\xEB^\x0E\xD4\x85\xCC\xD5\xF0\xBC\x9BT\xB3}\eRu\xD8\x8C\xB0\xCE\xA4\bwi\x9A\xD3a\xAAn\x0Ee\x10\x01\xE7\xFF1\xFA\x12\x04\xBEZ\xF5\x90\xA1\x95.7\xA5\rzJ\xDC~\x04;\xE4\xC1\xE9\x84w|)"}, @default_proc=nil>>, "action_dispatch.http_auth_salt"=>"http authentication", "action_dispatch.signed_cookie_salt"=>"signed cookie", "action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_salt"=>"encrypted cookie", "action_dispatch.encrypted_signed_cookie_salt"=>"signed encrypted cookie", "action_dispatch.cookies_serializer"=>:json, "action_dispatch.cookies_digest"=>nil, "rack.session"=>{}, "rack.session.options"=>{:key=>"rack.session", :path=>"/", :domain=>nil, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :defer=>false, :renew=>false, :sidbits=>128, :cookie_only=>true, :secure_random=>SecureRandom, :id=>"14e3e35975e7a758051ecf0751adcac0"}, "action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"=>{:controller=>"cities", :action=>"index"}}, @filtered_parameters=nil, @filtered_env=nil, @filtered_path=nil, @protocol=nil, @port=nil, @method=nil, @request_method=nil, @remote_ip=nil, @original_fullpath=nil, @fullpath=nil, @ip=nil, @uuid=nil>, "response"=>#<ActionController::TestResponse:0x00000006189268 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x000000061891c8>, @stream=#<ActionDispatch::Response::Buffer:0x00000006189128 @response=#<ActionController::TestResponse:0x00000006189268 ...>, @buf=[], @closed=false>, @header={}, @status=200, @sending_file=false, @blank=false, @cv=#<MonitorMixin::ConditionVariable:0x00000006189100 @monitor=#<ActionController::TestResponse:0x00000006189268 ...>, @cond=#<Thread::ConditionVariable:0x000000061890d8>>, @committed=false, @sending=false, @sent=false, @content_type=nil, @charset=nil, @cache_control={}, @etag=nil>, "params"=>{}}, @_controller=#<ActionView::TestCase::TestController:0x00000006192f48 @_action_has_layout=true, @_routes=nil, @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}, @_status=200, @_request=nil, @_response=nil, @request=#<ActionController::TestRequest:0x00000006192e08 @env={"rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x00000007b1a808>, "rack.errors"=>#<StringIO:0x00000007b1a8a8>, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>true, "rack.run_once"=>false, "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", "SERVER_NAME"=>"example.org", "SERVER_PORT"=>"80", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "rack.url_scheme"=>"http", "HTTPS"=>"off", "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "CONTENT_LENGTH"=>"0", "HTTP_HOST"=>"test.host", "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"0.0.0.0", "HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"Rails Testing", "action_dispatch.routes"=>#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x000000059671c0>, "action_dispatch.parameter_filter"=>[:password], "action_dispatch.redirect_filter"=>[], "action_dispatch.secret_token"=>nil, "action_dispatch.secret_key_base"=>"7368248a4a51e0ae4789e5f6d20884c032289b9da1a1e916d817efebed052e961d299ed73a8e8b90f33ed9314bb24454845f9ddc3acf18445aa3f6625ed9db63", "action_dispatch.show_exceptions"=>false, "action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"=>true, "action_dispatch.logger"=>#<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x000000057f3ca8 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x000000057f3b90 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x00000001f097f8 @datetime_format=nil>, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x000000057f3b40 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<File:/home/nafaa/RailsProjects/curiocity/log/test.log>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x000000057f3b18 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x000000057f3ac8>>>>, "action_dispatch.backtrace_cleaner"=>#<Rails::BacktraceCleaner:0x0000000618a0c8 @filters=[#<Proc:0x00000006189fb0@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:14>, #<Proc:0x00000006189f88@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:15>, #<Proc:0x00000006189f38@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:16>, #<Proc:0x00000006189ba0@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:29>], @silencers=[#<Proc:0x00000006189b78@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:19>], @root="/home/nafaa/RailsProjects/curiocity/">, "action_dispatch.key_generator"=>#<ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator:0x00000007888a68 @key_generator=#<ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator:0x00000007888a90 @secret="7368248a4a51e0ae4789e5f6d20884c032289b9da1a1e916d817efebed052e961d299ed73a8e8b90f33ed9314bb24454845f9ddc3acf18445aa3f6625ed9db63", @iterations=1000>, @cache_keys=#<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x00000007888a40 @backend={"signed_global_ids64"=>"4\xAC\xEB^\x0E\xD4\x85\xCC\xD5\xF0\xBC\x9BT\xB3}\eRu\xD8\x8C\xB0\xCE\xA4\bwi\x9A\xD3a\xAAn\x0Ee\x10\x01\xE7\xFF1\xFA\x12\x04\xBEZ\xF5\x90\xA1\x95.7\xA5\rzJ\xDC~\x04;\xE4\xC1\xE9\x84w|)"}, @default_proc=nil>>, "action_dispatch.http_auth_salt"=>"http authentication", "action_dispatch.signed_cookie_salt"=>"signed cookie", "action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_salt"=>"encrypted cookie", "action_dispatch.encrypted_signed_cookie_salt"=>"signed encrypted cookie", "action_dispatch.cookies_serializer"=>:json, "action_dispatch.cookies_digest"=>nil, "rack.session"=>{}, "rack.session.options"=>{:key=>"rack.session", :path=>"/", :domain=>nil, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :defer=>false, :renew=>false, :sidbits=>128, :cookie_only=>true, :secure_random=>SecureRandom, :id=>"14e3e35975e7a758051ecf0751adcac0"}, "action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"=>{:controller=>"cities", :action=>"index"}}, @filtered_parameters=nil, @filtered_env=nil, @filtered_path=nil, @protocol=nil, @port=nil, @method=nil, @request_method=nil, @remote_ip=nil, @original_fullpath=nil, @fullpath=nil, @ip=nil, @uuid=nil>, @response=#<ActionController::TestResponse:0x00000006189268 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x000000061891c8>, @stream=#<ActionDispatch::Response::Buffer:0x00000006189128 @response=#<ActionController::TestResponse:0x00000006189268 ...>, @buf=[], @closed=false>, @header={}, @status=200, @sending_file=false, @blank=false, @cv=#<MonitorMixin::ConditionVariable:0x00000006189100 @monitor=#<ActionController::TestResponse:0x00000006189268 ...>, @cond=#<Thread::ConditionVariable:0x000000061890d8>>, @committed=false, @sending=false, @sent=false, @content_type=nil, @charset=nil, @cache_control={}, @etag=nil>, @params={}, @_view_context_class=#<Class:0x000000061886d8>, @_lookup_context=#<ActionView::LookupContext:0x00000003d21060 @details_key=nil, @details={:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}, @skip_default_locale=false, @cache=true, @prefixes=["", "cities"], @rendered_format=nil, @view_paths=#<ActionView::PathSet:0x00000003d20fe8 @paths=[#<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x00000005951ff0 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x00000005951fc8 @data=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache::SmallCache:0x00000005951fa0 @backend={}, @default_proc=#<Proc:0x000000032a5230@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:49 (lambda)>>>, @path="/home/nafaa/RailsProjects/curiocity/app/views">, #<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x000000059535a8 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x00000005953418 @data=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache::SmallCache:0x00000005953328 @backend={}, @default_proc=#<Proc:0x000000032a5230@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:49 (lambda)>>>, @path="/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views">]>>, @_view_renderer=#<ActionView::Renderer:0x00000003d20ef8 @lookup_context=#<ActionView::LookupContext:0x00000003d21060 @details_key=nil, @details={:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}, @skip_default_locale=false, @cache=true, @prefixes=["", "cities"], @rendered_format=nil, @view_paths=#<ActionView::PathSet:0x00000003d20fe8 @paths=[#<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x00000005951ff0 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x00000005951fc8 @data=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache::SmallCache:0x00000005951fa0 @backend={}, @default_proc=#<Proc:0x000000032a5230@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:49 (lambda)>>>, @path="/home/nafaa/RailsProjects/curiocity/app/views">, #<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x000000059535a8 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x00000005953418 @data=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache::SmallCache:0x00000005953328 @backend={}, @default_proc=#<Proc:0x000000032a5230@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:49 (lambda)>>>, @path="/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views">]>>>, @_config={}>, @_request=#<ActionController::TestRequest:0x00000006192e08 @env={"rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x00000007b1a808>, "rack.errors"=>#<StringIO:0x00000007b1a8a8>, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>true, "rack.run_once"=>false, "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", "SERVER_NAME"=>"example.org", "SERVER_PORT"=>"80", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "rack.url_scheme"=>"http", "HTTPS"=>"off", "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "CONTENT_LENGTH"=>"0", "HTTP_HOST"=>"test.host", "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"0.0.0.0", "HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"Rails Testing", "action_dispatch.routes"=>#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x000000059671c0>, "action_dispatch.parameter_filter"=>[:password], "action_dispatch.redirect_filter"=>[], "action_dispatch.secret_token"=>nil, "action_dispatch.secret_key_base"=>"7368248a4a51e0ae4789e5f6d20884c032289b9da1a1e916d817efebed052e961d299ed73a8e8b90f33ed9314bb24454845f9ddc3acf18445aa3f6625ed9db63", "action_dispatch.show_exceptions"=>false, "action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"=>true, "action_dispatch.logger"=>#<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x000000057f3ca8 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x000000057f3b90 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x00000001f097f8 @datetime_format=nil>, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x000000057f3b40 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<File:/home/nafaa/RailsProjects/curiocity/log/test.log>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x000000057f3b18 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x000000057f3ac8>>>>, "action_dispatch.backtrace_cleaner"=>#<Rails::BacktraceCleaner:0x0000000618a0c8 @filters=[#<Proc:0x00000006189fb0@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:14>, #<Proc:0x00000006189f88@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:15>, #<Proc:0x00000006189f38@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:16>, #<Proc:0x00000006189ba0@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:29>], @silencers=[#<Proc:0x00000006189b78@/home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:19>], @root="/home/nafaa/RailsProjects/curiocity/">, "action_dispatch.key_generator"=>#<ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator:0x00000007888a68 @key_generator=#<ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator:0x00000007888a90 @secret="7368248a4a51e0ae4789e5f6d20884c032289b9da1a1e916d817efebed052e961d299ed73a8e8b90f33ed9314bb24454845f9ddc3acf18445aa3f6625ed9db63", @iterations=1000>, @cache_keys=#<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x00000007888a40 @backend={"signed_global_ids64"=>"4\xAC\xEB^\x0E\xD4\x85\xCC\xD5\xF0\xBC\x9BT\xB3}\eRu\xD8\x8C\xB0\xCE\xA4\bwi\x9A\xD3a\xAAn\x0Ee\x10\x01\xE7\xFF1\xFA\x12\x04\xBEZ\xF5\x90\xA1\x95.7\xA5\rzJ\xDC~\x04;\xE4\xC1\xE9\x84w|)"}, @default_proc=nil>>, "action_dispatch.http_auth_salt"=>"http authentication", "action_dispatch.signed_cookie_salt"=>"signed cookie", "action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_salt"=>"encrypted cookie", "action_dispatch.encrypted_signed_cookie_salt"=>"signed encrypted cookie", "action_dispatch.cookies_serializer"=>:json, "action_dispatch.cookies_digest"=>nil, "rack.session"=>{}, "rack.session.options"=>{:key=>"rack.session", :path=>"/", :domain=>nil, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :defer=>false, :renew=>false, :sidbits=>128, :cookie_only=>true, :secure_random=>SecureRandom, :id=>"14e3e35975e7a758051ecf0751adcac0"}, "action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"=>{:controller=>"cities", :action=>"index"}}, @filtered_parameters=nil, @filtered_env=nil, @filtered_path=nil, @protocol=nil, @port=nil, @method=nil, @request_method=nil, @remote_ip=nil, @original_fullpath=nil, @fullpath=nil, @ip=nil, @uuid=nil>, @view_flow=#<ActionView::OutputFlow:0x0000000615bde0 @content={}>, @output_buffer="", @virtual_path=nil, @rendered_views=#<ActionView::TestCase::Behavior::RenderedViewsCollection:0x0000000615bca0 @rendered_views={}>> does not implement: cities
     # ./spec/views/cities/index.html.slim_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
     # /home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
     # /home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
     # /home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
     # /home/nafaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@curiocity/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I use `rspec-rails 3.3.3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stub a controller helper method in a view spec with RSpec 3.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240236/how-can-i-stub-a-controller-helper-method-in-a-view-spec-with-rspec-3-4)